# what is the fastest way to populate a pandas dataframe from two for loops?

Tags: python, pandas

I already have a dataframe and I need to do computations at each index with respect to all preceding indices (so for 187 indicies there are 17766 computations). This needs to be efficient as to scale up to millions of computations.

```
#this is the original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(187,2))
#this is the dataframe to write to
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
#blank list to write to
ind_diff = []
```

Method 1: List

```
for n in range(0, len(df)):     

    for i in range(n + 1, len(df)):

        ind_diff.append(df.index[i] - df.index[n])
```

Method 2: Dataframe append

```
for n in range(0, len(df)):     

    for i in range(n + 1, len(df)):

        df2 = df2.append(df.Index[i] - df.Index[n])
```

Method #1 only returns the final calculation as output i.e. a list of length 1. Why is that?
Method #2 works but is way too slow. I know that this is not a recommended way of creating a dataframe (as per the documentation and that `pd.concat` is more efficient) but am looking for the quickest approach. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a sample input and expected output

Comment: Are you actually computing differences or is that a simplification for the question?

Comment: @wwii: The calculations are: index differences as demonstrated, datetime objects resulting in timedeltas, and simple arithmetic

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you could modify the code so it did not raise `AttributeError`s.

Comment: @ubuntu: I don't receive this error

Comment: @RafaelC: ok will do this asap

Comment: `hasattr(df, 'Index') --> False`

Answer (score 4):

Let's try broadcasted array arithmetic:

```
v = df.values
v = v - v[:, None]
i, j = np.triu_indices(df.shape[0])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(v[i, j])
```

This is *very* fast, but can quickly get out of hand for too many records (~millions) because it results in a memory blowout, and half the computations are redundant (because of the symmetry).

Comment: I've never heard of this before thanks for the speedy response. I will test it out. By records you mean the original df right? this shouldn't ever be any longer than 40k records

Comment: Why not just `df3 = pd.DataFrame(v[i,j])`?

Comment: @wwii Thanks. I clearly need a little more sleep; didn't spot that.

Comment: @coldspeed: sory for the slow response. Your answer at any rate is correct and has been accepted.I had wanted to update my question for fullness before accepting in case there were edits/additional comments. For my full dataframe it timed out with 40k records, however on single columns it was amazingly fast. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @coldspeed: So instead of performing a calculation if I just wanted the former or latter value 
<code>
    v = (df['Type'].values)
    i, j = np.triu_indices(df.shape[0])

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(v[i]) 
<\code>
would achieve this (in this case for the source index i.e. i)

Comment: @tripkane v[i] gives you the entire row.

Comment: @coldspeed: yes in this case that is what I wanted 189 instances of the index 0 and so on. and j is from 0 to 188 in sequence also what I need. Got is sussed. Thanks again

Comment: @coldspeed: `i,j = np.triu_indices(n), n> 15000` starts failing and returning a Memory error / and above 50000 "iterator is too large" Error. Are you seeing the same results?

Comment: @tripkane It seems like `triu_indices` fails for large numbers.... hmm, this is going to be problematic. Let me get back to you in a while.